# get correct status of PM2 application after deploy/redeploy

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment, pm2

I'm trying to use PM2 for deployment purposes, and so at the end of my deployment process I do

```
pm2 startOrReload staging.json --env preprod
```

and I get this :

```
16:26:12 ‘staging/current’ -> ‘/srv/pb/dev/v0.0.6-85-g755a611’
16:26:12 [PM2] Applying action reloadProcessId on app [pb1](ids: 0)
16:26:13 [PM2] [pb1](0) ✓
16:26:13 ┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
16:26:13 │ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory      │ watching │
16:26:13 ├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
16:26:13 │ pb1      │ 0  │ fork │ 30180 │ online │ 111     │ 0s     │ 19.805 MB   │  enabled │
16:26:13 └──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

as you can notice the **status is online** regardless of the deploy being sucessfull or not;
And is marking the Jenkins build as success when is not. immediately afterward if you do a

```
pm2 list
```

you get the correct status **offline**

So is there a way to get the correct status via API or something so that I can mark the build as failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can get the current status in the JSON format from CLI:

```
pm2 jlist
pm2 prettylist
```

2) Or you can connect to pm2 instance programmatically:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect( function(err) {
  if (err) process.exit();

  pm2.list( function(err,list) {
    list.forEach( function(e) {
      console.log( e.name, e.pm2_env.status );
    });
    pm2.disconnect();
  });

});
```

3) Or you can use [keymetrics monitoring](https://app.keymetrics.io/).